# Missing test coverage pytest python class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, code-coverage, pytest-cov

I am testing my code with pytest --cov but one of my modules gets 0% coverage.

The module has one class declaration as such:

```
class DataBaseMaker:
    @staticmethod
    def create_database():
        conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'bar'
```

The test does the following:

```
def test_create_database():
    DataBaseMaker.create_database()
    assert Path("database.db").is_file()
```

Test coverage for this is 0% - what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hard to say with a reproducible case, but it sounds like you aren't running the file you think you are.  Try adding an exception to create_database, and see if the test fails.

Comment: @Ned Thanks for replying. I guess I am running the correct tests and files as the database file gets created when running the tests. Also all tests pass. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: It's very easy to have another copy of the code, either because of an editing mistake, or an extra installation, or other reasons.

Comment: @Ned I don’t. This project lives in one folder with main.py in the root folder and a modules folder containing the DataBaseMaker.py with the mentioned class and a test folder with the Python file containing the test. It‘s literally 3 files + requirements.txt and the stuff pytest and coverage generate.

Comment: It's a mystery.  I wish I had the answer for you.

Comment: See the answer I posted. If you have an explanation for that I'd be so happy to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find out what the issue is. It was not with the code itself but with my invocation of pytest. I did `pytest --cov *projectname*` where *projectname* was also the name of the folder the project is in. I think I got this from the pytest documentation? Not sure.

The solution: I ran `pytest --cov .` and sure enough my classes have 100% coverage now. If someone has an explanation for that behavior I'd be happy to learn.

Comment: You told coverage to only measure the code in the *projectname* directory.  By changing to . you told it to measure any code found within the current directory.  But isn't your DataBaseMaker class in the projectname directory? It should have been measured.

Comment: It is. Structure is projectname/class.py and projectname/tests/testclass.py so both are in the same directory.

Comment: If you can package up the code and commands in a way for other people to reproduce the problem, we might be able to find a good answer.